# What is wrong with my syntax iterating through an array of strings?

Tags: jquery, arrays

```
array_of_strings = ["this", "is", "my", "array", "of", "strings"]

array_of_strings.each(function(val, i) {  console.log(i)  })
```

Which returns :

```
TypeError: Object has no method 'each'
```

I thought I could iterate through an array this way..

Comment: the .each is for a jQuery objects.. you need to use $.each for objects and arrays

Comment: Arrays don't have an `each` method, you're mixing jQuery objects and arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have is for iterating jQuery objects. You should use `$.each` like below,

```
//                       index----v   v-----value
$.each(array_of_strings, function(i, val) {  console.log(val)  });
```

Also the params inside `$.each` function is `(index,value)`